# If I know the url, how to find the file in S3 in the AWS Management Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, url, amazon-s3

I have this URL, but I can't find it in any of the S3 buckets. I'm quite sure that I'm logged in with the same AWS account as I did when I uploaded it. I might be mistaken of course. All the buckets I can see in the AWS Management Console (logged in with a root account) have URLs that start with `http://[bucket-name].s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`

How can I reverse engineer the Amazon account and S3 bucket that this file is placed in?

https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ac-mail/footer.jpg

My end goal is to replace the file with another one. But I first need to find it.

Comment: WIth a URL in this format. The bucket name is the first part of the suffix after the FQDN. So in this case it's ac-mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [bucket name](http://[]%20Working%20with%20Amazon%20S3%20Buckets%20-%20Accessing%20a%20Bucket%20-%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#access-bucket-intro) is "ac-mail". I believe it is not possible to find the owner account of the bucket just from the bucket name unless you own the bucket or you have the permission via the bucket policy. In that case, the command will be: aws s3api get-bucket-acl --bucket ac-mail

** It does return the canonical id of the owner.

Comment: Thanks. Using that command, I now know that the canonical user id of the owner of the bucket is different from the canonical user id of the root account that I log in with. I'm now quite sure that I'm logged in with a **different** AWS account as I did when I uploaded it (that was a few years back). :)