# Get account email address from a canonical user id of an AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, account

I [now know the canonical user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53655683/if-i-know-the-url-how-to-find-the-file-in-s3-in-the-aws-management-console) of an AWS account that I created an S3 bucket with a few years back.

Is there a way<sup>*</sup> to get the user email address that is associated with that canonical user id<sup>**</sup>?

With that email address, I can initiate a forgot password process with Amazon.com's Password Assistance.

<sup>* I cannot use the aws cli to do queries, since I don't have any credentials of the user account I'm trying to get access to.</sup>
<sup>** I only know the canonical user id and bucket name.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to obtain the email address.

You will need to contact AWS Support (or AWS Customer Service if you do not have Support) to obtain the information.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed we do not have support. So via https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/ I clicked on "I cannot login to my AWS account" (best match) and ended up filling in this form: https://pages.awscloud.com/contact-us-account-support.html . Now let's wait and see